# REST API Content builder updating assets results in 404

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, content-builder, patch

REST API Content builder updating assets results in 404
I'm trying to migrate to REST API and according to SFMC documentation in order to update of an asset using PATCH I should use https://my_sub_domain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/{id}. However, all requests end with

```
1string(747) "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found x-mashery-message-id: 8c94a90d-ba59-4c88-9dd8-0e8be18f2b8c x-mashery-responder: 07-rt06 strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; preload Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block x-frame-options: DENY x-content-type-options: nosniff cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin Vary: Origin, X-HTTP-Method-Override Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 147 Date: Mon, 04 May 2020 21:53:38 GMT Connection: keep-alive {"documentation":"https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm","errorcode":404,"message":"Not Found"}"
```

JSon request

```
[{"name":"Test","assetType":{"id":"4963","name":"Test"},"views":{"subjectline":{"content":"test subject"},"html":{"content":"test content"}}}]
```

My code:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: Bearer ' . $token ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);   
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

What do I miss?

Note: I'm able to retrieve the same asset with no issues

Comment: Did you put the ID in the URL, or literally use `{id}`?

Comment: 404 on this endpoint means the  Asset was not found so my guess is that either you didn't add the Id (as per sfdcfox suggestion) or the Id doesnt exist within the Business Unit you are calling (try doing a get call on the same asset Id to see if you can find it)

Comment: @sfdcfox yes I do

Comment: @Doug asset does exist, I'm able to retrieve it without any issues

Comment: I also checked APP settings and everything rerlated to assets is checked.

Comment: You verified the default BU that the app uses is the one that contains the asset? The oAuth token is limited to a single BU - so unless you specify a clientID in the token request, it will pull only from the default.

Comment: @Gortonington, I'm able to retrieve content of the same asset using the same credentials

Comment: Your payload seems to be an array. Should just be the object.

Comment: Verify that the ID var is actually loading in. I can only get a 404 on that endpoint if I leave the ID part empty. Otherwise it returns error based on incorrect id.